# LaTex left arrow over letter in math mode

Tags: latex

I want to put a left arrow over letter in math mode. I am looking for exactly the reverse of the vector symbol in `\vec{x}`. I tried to put it with `\stackrel{\leftarrow}{x}`, but it doesn't look good.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about LaTeX

Comment: Also, see a similar question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15010/vecx-but-with-arrow-from-right-to-left

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use `\overleftarrow` to create a long arrow to the left.

```
\overleftarrow{blahblahblah}
```

[image: LaTeX output]

Comment: Grrrrrrrreat answer!

Comment: So easy solution!

Comment: Easy and simple, and most important it works without the extra packages
Thank you

Comment: Thanks! BTW, is there any stylish options for the arrow heads?